# Assigning a random textbox from an array properties

Tags: c#

I'm quite new to coding in c# and i'm having difficulty assigning properties to a random textbox from an array. Here is the code i am using:

```
TextBox[] peopletiles = { A2, A3, A4, A5,};
int totalpeople = 0; 

do
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int tile = random.Next(0, peopletiles.Length);
    tile.BackColor = Color.Purple;                    
    totalpeople += 1;
} while (totalpeople != Edit.peopleStart);
```

I'm trying to change the colour of a random textbox from the array "peopletiles" to purple and have this looped until the number of purple text boxes is equal to the value of "Edit.peopleStart"

Using the code above gives the error "'int' does not contain a definition for 'BackColor'"

Comment: You should describe the actual problem you're seeing (expected values vs. actual values)

Comment: The problem is that you're declaring a `new Random()` inside your loop. `Random` is seeded by the system clock, so when instantiated in a hard loop, it will produce the same number for quite a few iterations. Try moving the `Random random = new Random();` *before* the `do` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to set a property of an `int`, not of a textbox in this code:

```
int tile = random.Next(0, peopletiles.Length);
tile.BackColor = Color.Purple;
```

You want to try

```
var tile = peopletiles[random.Next(0, peopletiles.Length)];
tile.BackColor = Color.Purple;
```

Also, as remarked in a comment, you should not create a new `Random()` in your loop, but outside it (or even on Class level, just once)

Answer (score 1):

Take your `random` variable outside the loop, that is important when you use Random. Also you need to modify your loop a little bit. Use List instead and on each iteration choose random TextBox, change color and remove it from temporary list.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

var peopletiles = new List<TextBox>{ A2, A3, A4, A5,};
Random random = new Random();
for (var i = 0; i < Edit.peopleStar; i++)
{
    var index = random.Next(0, peopletiles.Length);
    peopletiles[index].BackColor = Color.Purple;
    peopletiles.RemoveAt(index);
}
```